# Get todays date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get the current date in Javascript in this format?

"M/D/YYYY"?

Thanks.

If this would be today it would be

"2/17/2011", if it was the 3rd it would be "2/3/2011".

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the docs yet? — https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)
```

I assigned each part into its own variable for this example so that it's more clear as to what it returns.

Answer (score 3):

Use the javascript `Date` object:

```
var d = new Date();
alert((d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 1):

Steven Levithan's (stevenlevithan.com) dateFormat function looks really versatile to me.

See:

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

In his code, he adds dateFormat in as a prototype method for Date.

```
// For convenience...
Date.prototype.format = function (mask, utc) {
    return dateFormat(this, mask, utc);
};
```

So you can use it as a method on a Date object.

```
var now = new Date();

var variable=now.format("m/dd/yy");

document.write(variable);
```

HTH

Rich