# jQuery set defaul value of date picker input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, datepicker

I am building a web app that uses a date picker to filter the search results of some event items.

The form submits via ajax just fine, (I am getting results) but I am having issues with setting a default value into the datepicker. The input type is text based, but it functions like a javascript DatePicker. Thanks for any help.

*Note: I did not build the form from scratch, but it is customized to do what I need it to.*

jQuery:

```
// Get current date
var date = new Date();

var month = date.getMonth()+1;
var day = date.getDate();
var year = date.getFullYear();

var currentDate = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;

$("#CAT_Custom_2_Min").val(currentDate)
$("#calendar-form").submit();
```

Form HTML:

```
<form id="calendar-form" action="/Default.aspx?CCID=17654&amp;FID=197248&amp;ExcludeBoolFalse=True&amp;PageID=11940414" method="post" name="catcustomcontentform95560">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" class="webform">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Event Start Time Min/Max:</label><br />
                <input type="text" onfocus="displayDatePicker('CAT_Custom_2_Min');return false;" style="background-color: #f0f0f0;" readonly="readonly" class="cat_textbox" id="CAT_Custom_2_Min" name="CAT_Custom_2_Min" /> 
                And <input type="text" onfocus="displayDatePicker('CAT_Custom_2_Max');return false;" style="background-color: #f0f0f0;" readonly="readonly" class="cat_textbox" id="CAT_Custom_2_Max" name="CAT_Custom_2_Max" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Search" class="cat_button" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Live Page: http://sevenclanscasino.designangler.com/warroad/warroad-calendar

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VJQYb/

Comment: You know you're submitting the form and redirecting ?

Comment: @adeneo Yes, I am able to submit with no dates put into the date fields and get back the entire list of events. It is pulling the information correctly. I just don't know how to set the default dates for the fields.

Comment: Oh, I was just wondering why you would you need datepickers when you're submitting the form with javascript anyway ?

Comment: did you try putting up the default dates in value field like <input type="text" value="08 Apr 2014" + other attributes

Comment: @adeneo I am submitting it by default the first time the user goes to the page. That way they have a default view of the current week of events. From there they can choose a different date range and get different results back. The form is submitted via Ajax.

Comment: @neo I need to be able to get the current date dynamically. If I had a function that got the current date, and another function that got the date a week from the current date, I could use those functions as the default values like you described.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034498/get-todays-date-in-javascript

Comment: @neo Unfortunately the platform I work on does not allow for server side code. Thanks though.

Comment: yeah i noticed it as soon as I posted the comment, now I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get current date
var date = new Date();

var month = date.getMonth()+1;
var day = date.getDate();

var currentDate = date.getFullYear() + '/' +
  (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
  (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day;

// Date for 7 days from current date 
var futureDate = new Date();
futureDate.setDate(date.getDate() + week);
$("#CAT_Custom_2_Min").val(currentDate);
$("#CAT_Custom_2_Max").val(futureDate);
$("#calendar-form").submit();
```

I removed the variable `d` as it wasn't being declared, and added a `#` in front of `CAT_Custom_2_Min` and `CAT_Custom_2_Max`

Comment: Yeah, I think my brain has shut down for the day. I don't know how I missed the id declarers. However after making changes to the code, I am still not getting the result I require.

Comment: I noticed `futureDate` isn't being set as a date so I just updated my code

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
<input type="text" id="date1" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var cdate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
document.getElementById("date1").value=cdate;
</script>
```

just an example to clear the idea of showing date in input box...

Comment: I wonder if it is not working because the field I am working with is using a javascript datepicker when the text field is focused.

Comment: I created a fiddle using your code, and I have no issues. It is only when I try to do it on the text field that has a javascript datepicker assigned to the onfocus property.

Comment: can you put everything in jsfiddle and share the link?

Comment: I posted link to fiddle. It seems to overwrite there.

Comment: why are you submitting it after placing a value, i thought you need to display current date by default and user will have a choice to change the dates and then submission will be initiated by user.

Comment: on focus code will also work in a normal manner : my code is meant to display the current date in the text box.

Comment: The reason for the submit is so that the first time the user lands on the page, it is not blank. The default will be that first week and they are able to change the dates and re-submit so that they can get different results. I want there to be something on the page the first time they load it.